# Date formatting with Excel VBA without Regex

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to include a specifically formatted date as a part of a long string.

Basic format: yyyy.mm.dd.

Goal format: yyyy/mm/dd

So I searched via google, got to this site and have found this answer:

```
String = Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

However, it's not working. I still get the "yyyy.mm.dd." format.

I have also found a solution that uses regular expressions to switch out characters (like how one does it with stream editor on a linux OS), but I would like to find a solution without using any extra functions.

So far I have come up with a not quite elegant solution:

```
CurYear = Year(Date)
CurMonth = Month(Date)
    If CurMonth < 10 Then
        CurMonth = "0" & CurMonth
    End If
CurDay = Day(Date)
     If CurDay < 10 Then
        CurDay = "0" & CurDay
    End If

Today = CurYear & "/" & CurMonth & "/" & CurDay
```

Comment: Dear brother your problem is as simple as 

    `MyDate = Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd")`

You cannot use the word 'String' as string, Just replace this you are good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you just need to replace you '.' with '/'. Therefore `Replace` function is most suitable:

```
myString = Replace(Date, ".", "/")
```

**EDIT** after comment:

If there is fix length of data string than you could do it as follows:

```
myString = Left(Replace(Date, ".", "/"), 10)
```

as a result last symbol is cut.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that function yet, seems to be handy.
However, this gives me: "yyyy/mm/dd/" so I get an extra "/".

Answer (score 0):

The cell formula to force a change would be:

```
=TEXT(A1,"yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Using vba:

Sub DateFix()

```
Dim dtStart As Date
Dim strFinish As String

    dtStart = ActiveCell.Value

    strFinish = Format(dtStart, "yyyy/mm/dd")

    MsgBox strFinish
```

End Sub

Comment: As I wrote in my post, the Format function doesn't do the job, it simply switches the numbers around but won't switch the dots to slashes.

Comment: It works on my test sheet. I set the cell format to "yyyy.mm.dd" and then ran that bit of code. My strFinish shows as "yyyy/mm/dd"

Comment: Problem is that the date is only a part of a much longer string, therefore I can not give the cell a date format.
As for the format function, sadly, it didn't give me the expected result.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad you found a fix.